# System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I uninstalled Xamarin Studio (since xamarin is free) and tried to run my app on VS and I got this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop

I have no idea how to fix this, already searched on the internet and found nothing.

Here is the log

```
    Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/Mono.Android.dll
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/Java.Interop.dll [External]
03-31 15:12:06.457 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x9e01f9a0] -> System.Collections.Concurrent[0xb43f0700]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.457 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System.Collections.Concurrent[0xb43f0700] -> mscorlib[0xb4250dc0]: 4
03-31 15:12:06.457 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x9e01f9a0] -> System.Reflection[0xb43fc700]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.457 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System.Reflection[0xb43fc700] -> mscorlib[0xb4250dc0]: 5
03-31 15:12:06.469 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x9e01f9a0] -> System.Threading[0x9e01f280]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.469 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System.Threading[0x9e01f280] -> mscorlib[0xb4250dc0]: 6
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x9e01f9a0] -> System.Diagnostics.Debug[0xb43f0a60]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Loader probing location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll'.
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Image addref System[0x9e01fbe0] -> /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll[0x9e023500]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly System[0x9e01fbe0] added to domain RootDomain, ref_count=1
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): AOT module '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): AOT module '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/lib/mono/aot-cache/x86/System.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libaot-System.dll.so" not found
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Loader loaded assembly from location: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll'.
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Config attempting to parse: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll.config'.
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Config attempting to parse: '/Users/builder/data/lanes/3053/a94a03b5/source/monodroid/builds/install/mono-x86/etc/mono/assemblies/System/System.config'.
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System.Diagnostics.Debug[0xb43f0a60] -> System[0x9e01fbe0]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.470 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System[0x9e01fbe0] -> mscorlib[0xb4250dc0]: 7
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/System.dll
03-31 15:12:06.475 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref Java.Interop[0x9e01f9a0] -> System.Runtime.InteropServices[0xb43fcac0]: 2
03-31 15:12:06.475 D/Mono    ( 2254): Assembly Ref addref System.Runtime.InteropServices[0xb43fcac0] -> mscorlib[0xb4250dc0]: 8
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport attempting to load: 'java-interop'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'java-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/java-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.478 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 W/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport attempting to load: 'java-interop'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'java-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/java-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.479 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/MaoNaRoda.Droid/files/.__override__/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.481 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.481 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.481 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.482 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop.so" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.482 D/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport error loading library 'libjava-interop': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
03-31 15:12:06.482 W/Mono    ( 2254): DllImport unable to load library 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/MaoNaRoda.Droid-1/lib/x86/libjava-interop" not found'.
Unhandled Exception:

System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop
```

more details

```
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743): 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743): Unhandled Exception:
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743): System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods:java_interop_jnienv_get_java_vm (intptr,intptr&)
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+References.GetJavaVM (IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr& vm) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:163 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironmentInfo.set_EnvironmentPointer (IntPtr value) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:190 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironmentInfo..ctor (IntPtr environmentPointer, Java.Interop.JniRuntime runtime) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:215 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniRuntime..ctor (Java.Interop.CreationOptions options) [0x00105] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniRuntime.cs:192 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Android.Runtime.AndroidRuntime..ctor (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr vm, Boolean allocNewObjectSupported, IntPtr classLoader, IntPtr classLoader_loadClass) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs:17 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono    ( 2743):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.Initialize (Android.Runtime.JnienvInitializeArgs* args) [0x00168] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:237 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: java-interop
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods:java_interop_jnienv_get_java_vm (intptr,intptr&)
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+References.GetJavaVM (IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr& vm) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:163 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironmentInfo.set_EnvironmentPointer (IntPtr value) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:190 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironmentInfo..ctor (IntPtr environmentPointer, Java.Interop.JniRuntime runtime) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniEnvironment.cs:215 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Java.Interop.JniRuntime..ctor (Java.Interop.CreationOptions options) [0x00105] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniRuntime.cs:192 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Android.Runtime.AndroidRuntime..ctor (IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr vm, Boolean allocNewObjectSupported, IntPtr classLoader, IntPtr classLoader_loadClass) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/AndroidRuntime.cs:17 
03-31 16:23:23.607 E/mono-rt ( 2743):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.Initialize (Android.Runtime.JnienvInitializeArgs* args) [0x00168] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2923/a908ff16/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.cs:237
```

Comment: Please include any various logs you can. Did you also create this forum post? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/63676/system-dllnotfoundexception-java-interop - If so, please include the logs from the forum post into this question so it's more relevant to the error at hand.

Comment: Thx @JonDouglas I'm new at posting on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for filing the corresponding bug report: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40031. Thanks also for your follow-up comment on that bug where you mentioned that you were able to solve the problem by:

1. Uninstalling the old version of the app from the device.
2. Redeploying the new version of the app to the device.

It sounds like those steps should resolve the problem for anyone else who might hit the issue too.

(As a side note, there is an upcoming fix for another related bug where "stale" on-device files caused an error. I think that fix will hopefully help prevent this kind of problem in the future.)